# UIImagePickerController language not changed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

In my app used

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"fr"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

this func to change app language.

It working fine all labels,button and all other elements. but, it is not replicated in UIImagePickerController.

Language change when i kill and reopen the app.
pls any suggestion.
Advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to synchronize your NSUserDefaults and change it like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"fr" forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Next you need to use the macro :

```
NSLocalizedString(string, nil)
```

for the text inside your UIImagePickerController.

Comment: first My thanks to u. But how can i change "saved photos" (photo album name).

Comment: You can't change the album name sorry.

Comment: my best Thank u for response.

Answer (score 1):

I change in `Info.plist` file string `Localization native development region` to my language, and then in app `UIImagePickerController` changed language. Maybe and for you it will work.