# Spanish support for Retake and Use photo buttons of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, nslocalizedstring, ios-camera

I am developing an app that supports Spanish content, which i am achieving through localised strings.

Now i would like to know if there is any way to give Spanish support for the buttons `Retake` and `Use Photo` of **UIImagePickerController**

Have attached image below for reference.

[image]

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781795/uiimagepickercontroller-language-not-changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i have the answer for it. We cannot get the spanish text working in this scenario because app level language is spanish language & Device level language is English.

`UIImagePickerController` button text `Retake` and `Use photo` is something that is generated and handled by the operating system by itself. Hence it tends to take the device level language.

Answer (score 5):

Go to project navigator -> Add Spanish language under localization.

[image: See the image]

Make sure device language is set to Spanish.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have given the spanish support for the whole app. I want to know how to give the spanish support for the buttons `Retake` and `Use Photo` of **UIImagePickerController**

Comment: Make sure device language is set to Spanish, unless and until you do that u don't get to see spanish language for buttons Retake and Use Photo. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, i tried and it works. A small clarification, with device language set as english, we cannot get the spanish text working [app level - spanish language] for the buttons rite? :)